# Is it possible to use "find" method with "javascript" query with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

With Mongo, it is OK with the following:

```
> db.posts.find("this.text.indexOf('Hello') > 0")
```

But with pymongo, when executing the following:

```
for post in db.posts.find("this.text.indexOf('Hello') > 0"):
    print post['text']
```

the error occurred.

I think [Full Text Search in Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo) is better way in this example, but is it possible to use "find" method with "javascript" query with pymongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct - you do this with server side javascript by using the $where clause[1]:

```
db.posts.find({"$where": "this.text.indexOf('Hello') > 0"})
```

Will work on all but sharded setups but the costs of doing are deemed prohibitive as you will be inspecting all documents in the collection, which is why generally its not considered a great idea.

You could also do a regular expression search:

```
db.posts.find({'text':{'$regex':'Hello'}})
```

This will also do a full collection scan as the regular expression isn't anchored (if you anchor a regular expression for example you're checking if a field begins with an value **and** have an index on that field you can utilise the index).

Given that those two approaches are expensive and won't perform or scale well then the best approach?

Well the full text search approach as described in the link you gave[2] works well.  Create a _keywords field which stores the keywords as lowercase in an array, index that field then you can query like so:

```
db.posts.find({"_keywords": {"$in": "hello"});
```

That will scale and utilises an index so will be performant.

---

[1] http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

[2] http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo